# ACS/RSS - How current SQL environment can be overridden to instead use current *LIBL of the job nnnnnn/QUSER/QZDASOINIT?

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

IBM i CLI (`QCMDEXC`): I've a file in library `DATALIB`, I do `CHGLIBL`, `RUNQRY` on the file and I get file data smoothly. Because *LIB `DATALIB` is in the `*LIBL`, it works fine.

I try to follow same on ACS's Run SQL Scripts, as below

```
CL: CHGLIBL LIBL(QTEMP TSTLIB1 DATALIB);
CL: CHGLIBL LIBL(QTEMP TSTLIB1 DATALIB) CURLIB(DATALIB);

SELECT * FROM DataFile;
```

`CHGLIBL` doesn't work, setting `DATALIB` as `*CURLIB` doesn't work either.

On checking the SQL Environment, I notice that while initiating RSS, the `CURRENT SCHEMA` gets set to `TESTUSER` (by default), and that is why I get the `SQLSTATE 42704` error (`SQLCODE -204`).

[image]

Request note: In addition to `[ibm-midrange]`, this issue is better scoped by tags `[ibm-acs]` and `[db2-sql]`. Looking at the acceptability and growing use of IBM ACS and DB2 for i SQL, I expected them to be in existence by now.
Anyways, I tried creating them but I was told that it requires at least 1500 reputation, which I clearly lacks rn. So, the reputed one, if you're reading so far, could you please do the needful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use System (*SYS) naming when running SQL statement on the IBM i in order for the library list to be searched for unqualified table.

`Edit` --> `JDBC Configurations`

You'll want the `Format` tab.
[image]

Also note you can figure the library list you want to use on `System` tab.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! This perfectly solved the problem.